# RPM fails to install because of a directory conflict even though permissions are the same

Tags: centos7, rpm

We build several RPM packages that install files under the common prefix

```
/usr/local/myorg
```

A recent RPM suddenly cannot install and `yum` throws the error

```
file /usr/local/myorg from install of some-package-1.0.9-9.x86_64 conflicts with file from package another-package-1.0-2.x86_64
```

I tested the content of both RPM files:

```
$ rpm -qp --dump some-package-1.0.9-9.x86_64.rpm
/usr/local/myorg 30 1709300602 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 040775 root root 0 0 0 X
... other files ...

$ rpm -qp --dump another-package-1.0.2.x86_64.rpm
/usr/local/myorg 28 1706541285 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000 040775 root root 0 0 0 X
... other files ...
```

Why would those two packages have a conflict? The permissions are exactly the same. Only the size and mtime differ, and for all I know, these shouldn't be a problem.

We build the RPM packages with CMake so I can't show a simple `.spec` file. This is on CentOS 7.9.2009.